# Installing prisma with vite-netlify project

Tags: mysql, prisma, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

In my project, I am trying to install prisma inorder to make a serverless function for registering with a mysql database (which located locally on my pc). So I follow these steps:

```
npm install prisma --save-dev
npx prisma init
```

After that a prisma folder was created inside my project with scheme.prisma, I changed it to this:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

And changed .env to this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:Mysqlpass@localhost:3306/mytable"
```

Now I ran this command **"prisma db pull"** and it changed my prisma.scheme file accordingly:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model users {
  username String @id @db.VarChar(12)
  email    String @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(254)
  password String @db.VarChar(24)
  date     String @db.VarChar(255)
}
```

If I run the command **"netlify dev"** the project works well with no errors. However, the moment I move to the next step which is creating the prisma client with **"prisma generate"** it does seem to work at first:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.4.1) to .\node_modules\@prisma\client in 104ms

Start using Prisma Client in Node.js (See: https://pris.ly/d/client)        

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

or start using Prisma Client at the edge (See: https://pris.ly/d/accelerate)

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client/edge'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

See other ways of importing Prisma Client: http://pris.ly/d/importing-client
```

BUT now when I run **"netlify dev"** I get this error:

```
◈ Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Ignored general context env var: LANG (defined in process)
◈ Injected .env file env var: MAPLE_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID     
◈ Injected .env file env var: MAPLE_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY   
◈ Injected .env file env var: RECAPTCHA_KEY
◈ Injected .env file env var: RECAPTCHA_CLIENT
◈ Injected .env file env var: ReCAPTCHA_LOCALHOST
◈ Injected .env file env var: DATABASE_URL
◈ Setting up local development server
◈ Starting Netlify Dev with Vite

> maplebgu-react@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.4.7  ready in 2019 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
✔ Waiting for framework port 5173. This can be configured using the 'targetPort' property in the netlify.toml

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                 │
   │   ◈ Server now ready on http://localhost:8888   │
   │                                                 │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

◈ Failed to load function recaptcha: Cannot read from `C:/Users/playe/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/MapleBGU/mapleBGU-react/node_modules/.prisma`: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
◈ Failed to load function register: Cannot read from `C:/Users/playe/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/MapleBGU/mapleBGU-react/node_modules/.prisma`: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
◈ Failed to load function contentful: Cannot read from `C:/Users/playe/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/MapleBGU/mapleBGU-react/node_modules/.prisma`: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

 »   Error: Netlify CLI has terminated unexpectedly
This is a problem with the Netlify CLI, not with your application.
If you recently updated the CLI, consider reverting to an older version by running:

npm install -g netlify-cli@VERSION

You can use any version from https://ntl.fyi/cli-versions.

Please report this problem at https://ntl.fyi/cli-error including the error details below.

NestedError: Cannot read from `C:/Users/playe/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/MapleBGU/mapleBGU-react/node_modules/.prisma`: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Module.createReadStream (file:///C:/Users/playe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/cp-file/fs.js:21:9) 
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at copyFileAsync (file:///C:/Users/playe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/cp-file/index.js:11:21)       
    at file:///C:/Users/playe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/netlify-cli/node_modules/p-map/index.js:141:20
Caused By: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.17.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 9.6.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 117.0.5938.134
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (118.0.2088.27)
```

I have 3 netlify serverless functions but none of them are using prisma yet and they are located inside "netlify-functions" folder. here is my netlify.toml file:

```
[build]
command = "npm run build"
publish = "dist"
functions = "netlify-functions/"
```

I was expecting to properly install Prisma with my Vite project and Netlify serverless functions.
At first, I tried to completely uninstall Prisma and do it again but nothing happened. also tried to work with chatGPT on it but didn't manage to get by either.